# Simplest Gson.fromJson example fails

Tags: android, gson

Given the following code:

```
final class retVal { int photo_id; }
Gson gson = new Gson();
retVal ret = gson.fromJson("{\"photo_id\":\"383\"}", retVal.class);
```

I get `ret` set to `null`.

I'm sure I've missed something obvious out, as `toJson` with a class also fails, although hand-construction through `JsonObject` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your class `retVal` outside the method.

Comment: Doh! I knew it had to be a stupid mistake. That works, thanks. Can you explain *why* it works, please?

Comment: GSON does not allow deserialization of local classes.

Answer (score 1):

Gson helps you to serialize objects. So, you need an object first. Based on your approach, you want to do something like

```
RetVal myRetVal = new RetVal();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(myRetVal);
```

To retrieve the object back from the string:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
RetVal myNewRetValObj = gson.fromJson(gsonString, RetVal.class);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, `toJson` also fails, and the string is coming from a REST API. The code works fine with the standard `JSONObject` class, but I thought I'd refactor with `Gson` to see how it worked.